# c# split string by underscore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working on some string generator task. I have some sample string duplicate_config_dev_V2 and I want to get output duplicate_config_dev. If input is duplicate_config_dev_V3 then I want to get duplicate_config_dev. I tried as below.

```
int countUnderScore = input.Count(c => c == '_');
if(countUnderScore > 0 )
{
    input = input.Split('_')[countUnderScore-1];
}
```

This code returns Dev as output but I want to return duplicate_config_dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the part after the last underscore, you can use the `LastIndexOf` method:

```
var input = "duplicate_config_dev_V2";
var index = input.LastIndexOf("_");
if (index >= 0)
  Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(0, index));
```

Output of above sample:

```
duplicate_config_dev
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem using String.Split() like you have started, but that means you will have to re-assembly the parts of the string.

Instead I would use .LastIndexOf() to find the index of the *last* underscore in the string, and then use .Substring() to get rid of it.

[String.LastIndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-lastindexof(system-string))

[String.SubString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32))

Comment: IndexOfLast -> LastIndexOf

Answer (score 0):

I'd very much consider using `Regex` here. It seems important that the string ends with `_V#` (# is some number).

This works:

```
var input = "duplicate_config_dev_V2";
var regex = new Regex(@"^(.*)_V\d+$");
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```